# Form to allow users to add text and store temporarily before inserting into database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arraylist, postback

I am developing a ASP.NET 3.5 web site and one of the pages I am building contains a form for which the user is adding names individually and once they have completed this step they move on to the next step, it is when they move to the next step that I want the data collected to be inserted into the database (MS SQL Server 2005) table.

Because the amount of entries will be dynamic I am not sure on what would be the best method for this temporary data collection.  I am thinking an arraylist would be easy to work with and have implemented a test with it, but the values are lost on post back.

So my question would be, is the arraylist a suitable solution for the storing of this data and who would I add the data when the user presses the Add button?

UPDATE:
I was able to use sessions, and in the Page_Load sub I added:

```
If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
  Session("recipients") = arrRecipients
Else
  arrRecipients = DirectCast(Session("recipients"), ArrayList)
End If
```

I am not sure if the use of sessions is the best idea (happy to hear peoples thoughts and suggestions for improvement on this one).

Comment: you want to save data of first step into database before move to step 2?

Comment: Yep, at most of the step the data collected will be inserted into the DB.  This isn't a big deal and it is only a 4-step process and probably only 2 steps (step 1, then finish) will insert data into different tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another Alternative to the mentioned list is to use the MultiView control. Show one tab and on button click hide the first tab and show second tab. In the second tab, you can add the submit button that can submit all the controls in both the tabs.
You can add previous button in second tab and to move back to the second tab.
An example for you illustration of MultiView

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_multi_views.htm

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19715/How-to-use-Multiview-Control-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Interesting, I was using the Wizard Control as there are other elements on my form but I was having an issue with this dynamic content part of the form.  Ill look further into this one.